# Responsive Width Width Limit

Tags: css

This may sound like a newb question but I just cannot find the answer.

I have implemented a few media queries and like the site look down to about `412px`.

Is there a way to "stop" the responsiveness and have devices such as an iPhone view the page at a minimum of `412px`?

I read that the iPhone responsive width is about `480px` so I am not sure if the chrome developer tools are showing an accurate width.

If I re-size my browser down to `412px` the site looks fine, but if I view it on my iPhone it seems to be zoomed in to about `300px`(guesstimate).

Comment: You could set the initial zoom level you want your page to be displayed at via the [`viewport` meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). (Apparently you can also set `user-scalable=false`, but whether a device will respect this might vary, and if that’s user-friendly is also very doubtful.)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I like to set a `min-width` property on my `body` tag. That way, the site will not reflow below that width.